# Use of discharge as Noun

Tags: sentence-construction

Are the below sentence constructions correct?

> a) He got a discharge from the hospital.
>    b) He has got a discharge
>   from the hospital.

To get can mean to receive. One can receive a discharge from the hospital.

> He has received a discharge from hospital.

So, in another way, can we say,

> He has got a discharge from the hospital.

Discharge can be used as a noun, meaning:
the action of discharging someone from a hospital or the armed forces or police.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a native British English speaker that works in hospital information, I can confirm that "discharge" is used as a noun, for example:

> We had 100 admissions and 100 discharges this morning.

It is quite common in any line of work for 'jargon' to develop, and for the names of *processes* to become the name for the *result* or *outcome* - for example, if you work in retail you might hear goods which have been returned called "returns" rather than "returned goods", but I could not find that particular definition in my dictionary.

I find no problem with either of your examples:

> a) He got a discharge from the hospital.
>   b) He has got a discharge from the hospital.

I would also expect to hear:

> - He got discharged from the hospital.
> - He got a discharge from the hospital.
> - He has been discharged from hospital.

The latter, "*he has been discharged from hospital*" is probably the most idiomatic.

Comment: Please find supporting evidence for "got a discharge from (the) hospital".

Comment: @Mari-LouA If you can "get a discharge" of any kind then logically you can get it *from* someone or something. Ngram shows it is used: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+a+discharge%2C+got+a+discharge+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20a%20discharge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20a%20discharge%20from%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgot%20a%20discharge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20a%20discharge%20from%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Compare your results with "was discharged" and "was discharged from" https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+a+discharge%2Cgot+a+discharge+from%2Cwas+discharged%2C+was+discharged+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20a%20discharge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20a%20discharge%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20discharged%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20discharged%20from%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't doubt there are more results from the others, but the phrase in question *is* used. I've stated which is most idiomatic, and it isn't that - but it is a variation of one of the suggestions contained within the OP so I can't ignore it, and I can't fault it. If you can demonstrate that it is grammatically incorrect then I will happily take it out.

Comment: You stated in a very recent edit which version was more idiomatic, almost as an afterthought, but the answer was originally posted on 12 September. And I asked that you provide supporting evidence, I never said the OP's examples were ungrammatical, but they are very odd-sounding and nowhere in your answer do you say this. `I find no problem with either of your examples` So, any visitor to this page in the future will presume that the OP's expressions are native-like, and natural sounding. If that is so, please find supporting evidence and place it IN the answer.

Comment: Not only is the use of "discharge" as a noun unusually, but when it is combined with "get" it infuses the whole thing with the sense of a release from obligation is if the hospital were the army or a lender.

Answer (score 3):

It is more correct to say:

> c) He has been discharged from the hospital.

If we look up "He has been discharged from the hospital" on [ludwig.com](https://ludwig.guru/s/has+been+discharged+from+hospital), we find these examples:

> - Nelson Mandela, 94, **has been discharged** from hospital. (*Independent*)
> - No arrests have been made and the victim **has been discharged** from hospital. (*The Guardian*)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. You have given another version .. But Are my versions grammatically incorrect?

Comment: *got discharged* is forbidden, only informally permitted in some dialects. *has got the discharge* has never ever been said by a native speaker, I bet.

Comment: Got means here to received. One can receive discharge from hospital. So can we say "He has received discharge from hospital. And in another way "He has got discharge from hospital"

Comment: @user4084 You seem to be using "discharge" as if it were a noun. In this context though, it is a verb, and usually written using passive voice. We say that a person is discharged from a hospital.

Comment: @TypeIA  a discharge can also be a formal document. This usage is more common with a military discharge than a hospital discharge, but it can be used in a hospital context. so "discharge" is most often a verb in this context, but can also be a noun.

Answer (score 3):

**discharge as noun in reference to hospitals:**

1) **What is hospital discharge?
When you leave a hospital after treatment, you go through a process called hospital discharge. A hospital will discharge you when you no longer need to receive inpatient care and can go home. Or, a hospital will discharge you to send you to another type of facility.**

Johns Hopkins University Hospital

[hospital discharge](https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/treatment-tests-and-therapies/hospital-discharge)

google results: About 3,540,000 results (0.48 seconds)

That said, **the verb** is **to be discharged** from (a) hospital.

2) military discharges

A military discharge is simply defined as a military member being released from their obligation to continue service in the armed forces.

The verb here is "to receive an honorable or dishonorable discharge

[military discharges](https://themilitarywallet.com/types-of-military-discharges/)

3) discharge of contract

means: to allow a party to not be bound by a contract

4) discharge of duties, to perform or execute duties.

Here are the most usual uses of discharge as a noun

5) discharge from a gun is the firing of a gun

6) discharge of a substance into some area [liquid or similar]

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/discharge)

Answer (score 1):

#### *Discharge* isn't used that way in this context.

While you can make an argument for using the word this way not being grammatically incorrect, technically, this is not the way that a native English speaker would describe the event of being released from the hospital (not in the U.S., at least).

The usage you suggest is common when discussing terms of military service ending, particularly if describing the conditions of the end of service:

> He received an *honorable discharge* from the Air Force.

Members of the military have an explicit obligation to do certain things and behave in certain ways while they are in the military, and the conditions under which they leave military service can continue to apply to their lives. For example, if someone is *dishonorably discharged* from the military they are legally required (in the U.S.) to say so when applying for jobs in the future.

So, while a person may have *been discharged* from the military, it may be the case that they also "have a *discharge*" which continues to describe them in the present.

Usage of *[discharge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discharge)* in this way is strongly related to employment, specifically (see definition 8).

---

The constructions in the question are a somewhat different situation. *Charge* is, in terms of a hospital stay, about a person being given over to the hospital for care. It is true that that person is a *charge* of the hospital. But *discharge* doesn't describe that person or an event which continues to be relevant to their identity into the future. Instead it only describes something that *happens to them:* they *are*, themselves, discharged from the hospital. The interpretation of *discharge* here is that they *physically leave the hospital*.

Further, a *discharge* is typically not something that a hospital can grant or withhold-- nearly all hospital stays are voluntary on the part of the patient, who can leave at any time they wish. Circumstances in which the patient may not choose to leave are generally described as being *committed* to the hospital, and a commitment ending is described as such (or the patient is *released* from the hospital, emphasizing that they were being *held* there previously).

In that light it makes less sense to describe someone as "getting" a discharge from the hospital, as it is not something the hospital can give, or decline to give.

I can't promise that there are no English-speaking regions where people use *discharge* as in the question, but it's definitely *not* typical usage. Whether or not it is technically acceptable according to a particular standard of grammar, this is not a good construction to convey your intended meaning in English.

---

If we leave these considerations aside, the constructions would be broadly OK. Try substituting a word used more typically as a concrete noun in such a case:

> He got a *bottle of medicine* from the hospital.
>
> He has got a *bottle of medicine* from the hospital.

These are correct because the *bottle of medicine* is a noun, which *he* received in the past. The second version indicates that *he* received the *bottle of medicine* in the past, continued to have it from then until the present, and *still has it today*.

Since *discharge* is not commonly used as a noun in this scenario (even if it technically *could be* so used) native speakers will tend to *think of it* as an action strictly in the past which may or may not apply to the present:

> He *has gotten* a discharge from the hospital

But again, this is really an idle question. Technically correct or not, the constructions in the question simply aren't used in English.

Comment: Discharge can be use and Noun meaning of which can be .
The action of discharging someone from a hospital or from the armed forces or police. This is as per Google dictionary.

Comment: Also, How you could say that Discharge is not given by doctor. Discharge from hospital is given by doctor after recovery of patient from illness and also after paying all related bills.

Comment: @user4084 I know what it says in the dictionary, but this the word *discharge* is *not used* by native speakers in this way when describing leaving a hospital. And you are mistaken about how being discharged from a hospital works (again, in the U.S.). I tried to explain that part in my answer, and I'm not sure what is unclear about it from your comment. If you can expand on what is unclear about it, I might be able to clarify.

Comment: Why cant we use dischage like it used in military. ? Doctor gives us discharge summary. Word discharge is fondly used in hospital.

Comment: @user4084 There is no big reason the word *could not* be used that way. It would be reasonable and not break any rules. But, for whatever reason, native English speakers *don't use* the word that way. There is a different construction which *is* used. I don't think that anyone would be confused about your meaning if you used the word *discharge* as you did in the question. But it would seem odd to a native English speaker hearing you phrase it that way, because the other construction is used nearly 100% of the time.

Comment: Note that "discharge" can also mean the formal document indicating the event. Thsi usage is also more common in the military case, where an "honorable discharge" is typically an actual document. But it can be used to refer to the formal notice that a hospital stay is over. I think this usage was more common in the past than it now is.

Answer (score 1):

### Let's have a look at `Discharge` as a noun:

**Discharge (noun):**

---

**([PERMISSION TO LEAVE](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/discharge))** -Official permission to leave the armed forces, a prison, or a hospital:

> The judge gave him a one-year conditional ***discharge***.
>
> The soldier received a dishonourable ***discharge*** for a disciplinary offence.

---

**(SUBSTANCE)** -The act of sending out waste liquid or gas:

> Thousands of fish were killed as a result of a ***discharge*** of poisonous chemicals from a nearby factory.

***OR*** -Liquid matter that comes from a part of the body and is often infected:

> A vaginal ***discharge***.

---

**(PERFORMANCE)** -The performance of duties or payment of money that is owed:

> The ***discharge*** of his duties.

---

**(LEAVING)** -The act of asking or allowing someone to leave a place, esp. a job:

> McCarthy held the rank of captain at the time of his ***discharge*** from the army.

***OR*** -A release from duty.

> She got a ***discharge*** from the army.

---

**(FIRING GUN)**[Uncountable] -The action of firing a gun:

> The ***[discharge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discharge)*** of a weapon.
>
> The police [stated](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stated) that some 50 rounds had been ***discharged***.

---

**(FINANCE)** -The end of a debt, or an official order that ends someone’s duty to pay a debt:

> Bankrupts must undergo credit counselling before receiving a ***discharge*** of their debts.

---

**(ENVIRONMENT)** -A waste substance that is sent into the air or water from a factory or business:

> $1 billion was spent to reduce the plant’s mercury ***discharge***.

---

**Depending on these informations:**

> He got a ***discharge*** from the hospital.
>
> He has got a ***discharge*** from the hospital.

**same as:**

> She got a ***discharge*** from the army.

Which is in the meaning of ***leaving some place or a job or duty*** and totaly correct usage!
But if your intention is to provide a meaning that refers to permission to leave then:

> He has received a ***discharge*** from hospital.

would be the correct usage.

Sources: *Cambridge Dictionary* and *Merriam-Webster*

Comment: Information gathered from several dictionaries, including Cambridge!

Answer (score 0):

If ultimately you are asking whether those two sentences are correct, the answer is ***yes*** they are; at least in IndE.

> *After the accused underwent a minor surgery, he immediately got a discharge from the hospital.*

That is from [IndiaTimes](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22got%20a%20discharge%20from%20the%20hospital%22&sxsrf=ACYBGNTSC064tNxi8Xt88vZ1abrYsBUCaw:1568824575428&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih4qH85trkAhVRfisKHe12A3oQ_AUICSgA&biw=1536&bih=715&dpr=1.25)

There it is used as a *noun.*

---

Now, can it be used as a verb? Yes, it can be.

> *...they discharged him from hospital on Monday.*

That is from [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-spanish/discharge).